# Symfony2 form builder mixed entity and non-entity

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I am attempting to build a "Project" class that has this as a table structure:

```
+--+----+------+
|ID|Name|Fields|
+--+----+------+
```

Creating the form builder class with the name is easy to do:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name', TextType::class)
    ;
}
```

However, I am trying to dynamically load the different fields that will be saved as a serialized array for the fields table. 
This is because the actual information saved about each project can change over time. 
For example, the administrator might choose to add a field like location or description. 
I have a separate table that looks like this:

```
+--+-----------+----------+
|ID|Field Title|Field Type|
+--+-----------+----------+
```

For example, a row in this table might be like `1 - location - text`. 
The goal is to load in the rows from this table and add it to the form builder. 
It would use something like this:

```
foreach ($fields as $field) {
    switch($field->getFieldType()) {
        case 'text':
            $form->add($field->getFieldTitle(), TextType::class);
            break;
    }
}
```

However, this is giving me an error sort of like this one:

> Neither the property "location" nor one of the methods "getLocation()", >"location()", "isLocation()", "hasLocation()", "__get()" exist and have public >access in class "AppBundle\Entity\Project".

Of course this makes sense, because "location" is not in the Project class.

How can I carry this out?
It would be great if I could add fields not associated with an entity to a form builder that has entity attachments.
Do I need to restructure the DB?

Thanks!

Comment: Please read [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#creating-form-classes) *(it's the official doc)* and specially the `mapped=>false` option for your form field

Comment: Bingo that's what I needed - I felt for some reason that it would require a much more involved solution than that. Thank you!